Modify Lot/ Serial Number Generation in Acumatica Production Order Maintenance Screen (AM201500)
I have to do a customization in the production order maintenance screen where in the line details tab there is a generate button to create the line in sequence 000001 and so on.
But I want to change it to grab the production number for example (PP000004) and the lot/serial number generated is PP000004-000001, PP000004-000002, PP000004-000003 and so on till the quantity to generate is satisfied. How to achieve this via customization? The generate button needs to be extended to change the Lot/ Serial number, I have created an override method but I get this error, any help would be appreciated!
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using PX.Objects.AM.GraphExtensions;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using PX.Objects.AM.Attributes;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Objects.AM.CacheExtensions;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AM;

namespace PX.Objects.AM
{
  public class ProdMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint>
{
#region Event Handlers

 // This method overrides the existing method tied to the Generate button
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void GenerateNumbers(Action baseMethod)
    {
        // Call the base method to keep existing functionality (optional)
        baseMethod?.Invoke();

        // Custom logic to generate Lot/Serial numbers based on production number
        var currentOrder = PXSelect<AMProdItem>.Select(Base).TopFirst;
        if (currentOrder == null) return;

        string productionNumber = currentOrder.ProdOrdID;

        // Get all generated material lines
        PXResultset<AMProdMatl> materialLines = PXSelect<AMProdMatl,
            Where<AMProdMatl.prodOrdID, Equal<Required<AMProdMatl.prodOrdID>>>>
            .Select(Base, currentOrder.ProdOrdID);

        int sequenceNumber = 1;
        foreach (AMProdMatl line in materialLines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.LotSerialNbr)) continue;

            // Generate the new lot/serial number
            string newLotSerialNbr = $"{productionNumber}-{sequenceNumber:D6}";

            // Update the lot/serial number
            line.LotSerialNbr = newLotSerialNbr;

            // Save changes
            Base.Caches[typeof(AMProdMatl)].Update(line);

            sequenceNumber++;
        }

        // Save changes to the database
        Base.Actions.PressSave();
    }

#endregion

}
}
Error: [2024-10-07 03:16:01.919] The Void GenerateNumbers(System.Action) method in the PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint_Extension graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but no original method with this name has been found in PXGraph.
[2024-10-07 03:16:08.479] Validation failed.
Thank you!
New Code
{
  public class ProdMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProdMaint.ItemLineSplittingExtension,PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint>
  {
 

    #region Event Handlers
    
  //public IEnumerable GenerateNumbersDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
  //public delegate IEnumerable GenerateNumbersDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
[PXOverride]
public IEnumerable GenerateNumbers(PXAdapter adapter, Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable> baseMethod)
{
    //var result = baseMethod(adapter);

    //return result;
    // Call the base method to ensure the original functionality is executed
    var baseResult = baseMethod.Invoke(adapter);

    // Retrieve the current production order
    var currentProductionOrder = PXSelect<AMProdItem>.Select(Base).TopFirst;
    if (currentProductionOrder == null)
    {
        throw new PXException("No Production Order found.");
    }

    // Get the production order number
    var productionOrderNbr = currentProductionOrder.ProdOrdID; // Adjust this field as needed

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productionOrderNbr))
    {
        throw new PXException("Production Order Number is required.");
    }

    // Prepare a list to store the updated rows
    var resultList = new List<AMProdMatl>();
    int sequenceNumber = 1;

    // Iterate over the results returned by the base method
   foreach (AMProdMatl row in baseResult.OfType<AMProdMatl>())
    {
      // Generate the custom Lot/Serial number
        row.LotSerialNbr = $"{productionOrderNbr}-{sequenceNumber:D6}";

        // Add the updated row to the result list
        resultList.Add(row);
        sequenceNumber++;
    }

    // Return the updated result list
    return resultList;
}

    #endregion
  }
}```


You get this error because GenerateNumbers is not declared in ProdMaint graph, but it is declared in ItemLineSplittingExtension. You need to override it in this way:
public class ProdMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ProdMaint.ItemLineSplittingExtension, PX.Objects.AM.ProdMaint>
{
    // This method overrides the existing method tied to the Generate button
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable GenerateNumbers(PXAdapter adapter, Func<PXAdapter, IEnumerable> baseMethod)
    {
        var baseResult = baseMethod.Invoke(adapter);
       
        var currentProductionOrder = Base.ProdMaintRecords.Current;
        if (currentProductionOrder == null) // I don't think it is possible
        {
            // Acuminator disable once PX1050 HardcodedStringInLocalizationMethod [Justification]
            throw new PXException("No Production Order found.");
        }

        // Get the production order number
        var productionOrderNbr = currentProductionOrder.ProdOrdID; // Adjust this field as needed

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productionOrderNbr))
        {
            // Acuminator disable once PX1050 HardcodedStringInLocalizationMethod [Justification]
            throw new PXException("Production Order Number is required.");
        }
        
        int sequenceNumber = 1;

        // Iterate over the splits records
        foreach (var row in Base.splits.Select().RowCast<AMProdItemSplit>())
        {
            // Generate the custom Lot/Serial number
            row.LotSerialNbr = $"{productionOrderNbr}-{sequenceNumber:D6}";
            Base.splits.Update(row);

            sequenceNumber++;
        }

        return baseResult; // or adapter.Get(); if you don't call baseMethod
    }
}


Hi thank you for the advice! I've added my code below could you please verify if possible?

I have updated my answer. Please not I use the current AMProdItem record from the screen, instead of the very first record from the AMProdItem table.

Noted, thank you so much!
